# Prevent Windows 10 from pushing windows into screen

Tags: windows, windows-10

On windows 10, windows have a 7-8 pixel invisible border. As such, setting a windows position to `(0,0)` actually (visual) sets it to `(7,0)`. To fix this instead have been setting the position to `(-7,0)`.

Basically the problem is is that when windows have negative coordinates, are focused, and the mouse is moved over that edge, it pushes the window back to a positive coordinate. This also happens with an autohidden taskbar, it will push the window so it is not under the taskbar when opened.

Is there any way to disable this feature and keep the windows in the original place.

Comment: Do you mean simply moving the mouse over the top of the window moves it, or when you click on it?

Comment: Neither. Put a window so the left half if it is off of the screen then move your cursor off the screen and it will move the window back into the screen, without clicking it

Comment: Out of interest, is your machine a Lenovo?

Comment: Yeah it's a ThinkPad t450s, do you think that could be causing it not windows?

Comment: Answer incoming ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having used a Lenovo work machine before, they often ship with some software pre-installed called `Auto Scroll Utility`.

Having been very confused what they could have been, I noticed the behaviour of moving my mouse to the edge of the screen causes the window to "float" the opposite direction to the mouse, which to be honest was quite helpful, but I believe that is what is causing your issues.

Try and uninstall the `Auto Scroll Utility` from Lenovo, and see if that resolves your issue, as this isn't a standard Windows feature.

For more information, see [here](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t450s/downloads/DS031944)

> This program provides a function to improve usability for window
> operation. Window position of the foreground application is
> automatically adjusted. And for Windows 8 style UI, scroll bar is
> automatically adjusted.

In case you need them, uninstall instructions from [here](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/gfvv22ew.txt)

> **Manual Uninstall**
>
> [Mouse and Keyboard]
>
> 1. Start Windows and logon with an administrator account.
> 2. Hold down the Windows logo key and press X to open a menu at the lower-left area of the screen.
> 3. Select Programs and Features from the menu.
> 4. Select "Lenovo Auto Scroll Utility", and select Uninstall or
>    Uninstall/Change.
> 5. Follow the instructions on the screen to complete uninstallation and
>    restart the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Access advanced display settings and there is a box you can un-check for auto scroll function. It stopped it from happening with me.